# Where to get normal boto3 reference?

Tags: python, documentation, boto3

I am starting to work with `boto3` with line

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-2')
```

Where to read, what is inside `s3`, which methods it has?

Next I do

```
bucket = s3.Bucket('sentinel-s2-l1c')
```

Where to read, what is inside `bucket`, which methods it has?

Next I do

```
object = bucket.Object(tilesdir + datestring + filename)
```

Where to read, what is inside `object`, which methods it has?

How to learn, what else is inside `bucket` besides `Object`? Where to get docs on `Object`, `Bucket` and `resource` methods or classes or whatever it is?

Is there any conventional way to list methods, properties and so on of classes, packages or whatever in Python?

**UPDATE**

Nothing is here of course http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/boto3.html

Comment: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The s3 docs [Jordon Phillips](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5314382/jordon-phillips) pointed you to will be the most complete resource for Boto3 methods. S3 is a large, complex world and the docs can be confusing to beginners. If you have a specific question, feel free to ask!

If you want a raw feed of the available methods and attributes available on any python object, you can use python's built-in [help function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help), e.g.:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-2')
>>> help(s3)
Help on s3.ServiceResource in module boto3.resources.factory object:

class s3.ServiceResource(boto3.resources.base.ServiceResource)
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      s3.ServiceResource
 |      boto3.resources.base.ServiceResource
 |      __builtin__.object
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  Bucket(self, *args, **kwargs)
 |      Creates a Bucket resource.::
-- More  --
```

If you are in a jupyter notebook, you can view the help file in a separate window using the syntax `s3?`.

Both of these functions will return contents derived from the attributes and methods on the objects, and documentation is derived from the `docstrings` associated with them.

For more information on documentation practices in python, see [the Hitchiker's guide](https://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/documentation/)